# Storage API y variables BLOB - Genexus 15 U9

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Configuré storage provider Amazon S3 y según entiendo en la documentación, no debiera funcionar con campos BLOB, pero está subiendo los archivos a S3...

Tengo un webpanel con una variable tipo BLOB que utilizo para importar y procesar un archivo excel. El tema es que luego de seleccionar el archivo y confirmar, se está haciendo upload del mismo a S3 y lo necesito procesar de forma local, no en s3.

Según la documentación, entiendo que este comportamiento debiera darse solo para imágenes, audio y video.

*** Sumo a lo anterior que ExcelDocument, al guardar las planillas, las está guardando en S3 también, lo cual me está complicando con todos los reportes del pattern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se encontró el work around para procesar archivos de forma local:

&StorageProvider.GetPrivate( &Blob, &File, 2, &Messages)
&ExcelDocument.Open( &File.GetURI() )

En la generación de excel de WWPlus, se agrega en los reportes excel:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se trabaja con external Storage, a partir de GeneXus 15 Upgrade 7 los archivos excel se graban en el storage provider, y esos pueden quedar privados.
En Java, los blobs también.
Referencias:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?36355,GeneXus+15+Upgrade+7,
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37491,GeneXus+15+Upgrade+9,
https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,,,42375
https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,,,42703